# I'm trying to identify a rose

Tags: identification

Color is pale violet pink, petal count 48, fragrance faint, plant has tall canes (untended for many years).
The blooms are urn-shaped buds that open into slightly curled back petals. Blooms are medium size.

Comment: IDK how to add photos.

Comment: I'm sure the bush has been in place for 40-50 years.

Comment: Carol, welcome! To add photos, first select [edit] to start editing your post, click in the text to select the place for your photo(s) then look for the photo icon (a camera symbol in the app, a mountain and a sun in the web version). Select that and the pop-up menu should guide you through the steps. If you still have problems, check that your pictures are not bigger than 2 MB, that’s a frequent issue with modern smartphones or cameras.